# 2.nd Translation Entity with KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors not working

Tags: symfony, translation

I am using symfony 3 and trying to get the categories translated with mysql db. That's why I am using KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors, which should be the best for symfony.

I have done all like it is discribed in the documentation.

**Category:**

```
    /**
 * MdCategories
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="md_category")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category implements ORMBehaviors\Tree\NodeInterface, \ArrayAccess
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable,
        ORMBehaviors\Sortable\Sortable,
        ORMBehaviors\Tree\Node;
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    protected $id;
```

**CategoryTranslation:**

/**
    * @ORM\Table(name="md_category_translation")
    * @ORM\Entity
    */
    class CategoryTranslation
    {
        use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation;

```
    /**
     * @var name
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=120, nullable=false)
     */

    protected $name;


    /**
     * @var route
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150)
     */
    protected $route;

    /**
     * @var metaKey
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $metaKey;

    /**
     * @var metaTitle
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */

    protected $metaTitle;

    /**
     * @var metaDescription
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=120)
     */

    protected $metaDescription;

    /**
     * @return name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name $name
     * @return Categories
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

       /**
     * @return route
     */
    public function getRoute()
    {
        return $this->route;
    }

    /**
     * @param route $route
     * @return Categories
     */
    public function setRoute($route)
    {
        $this->route = $route;
        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @return metaKey
     */
    public function getMetaKey()
    {
        return $this->metaKey;
    }

    /**
     * @param metaKey $metaKey
     * @return Categories
     */
    public function setMetaKey($metaKey)
    {
        $this->metaKey = $metaKey;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return metaTitle
     */
    public function getMetaTitle()
    {
        return $this->metaTitle;
    }

    /**
     * @param metaTitle $metaTitle
     * @return Categories
     */
    public function setMetaTitle($metaTitle)
    {
        $this->metaTitle = $metaTitle;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return metaDescription
     */
    public function getMetaDescription()
    {
        return $this->metaDescription;
    }

    public function setMetaDescription($metaDescription)
    {
        $this->metaDescription = $metaDescription;
        return $this;
    }

 public function __call($method, $arguments)
    {
        return $this->proxyCurrentLocaleTranslation($method, $arguments);
    }

}
```

**CategoryRepository:**

```
class CategoryRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    use ORMBehaviors\Tree\Tree;
}
```

**config.yml:**

```
knp_doctrine_behaviors:
    translatable:   true
    tree: true
    sortable: true
#     All others behaviors are disabled
```

and registering the bundle

```
new Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Bundle\DoctrineBehaviorsBundle(),
```

The databases are generated correctly

**But how do I fill the categoryTranslation Data with the right local ?**

```
$category = new Category;
$category->setCurrentLocale('de');
$category->setId(1); // tree nodes need an id to construct path.
$category->setName('Foobar');
$em->persist($category);
$em->flush();
```

**This did not work !**

I am surprised, that there is no KNP Translationsubscriber is listened in the subcribed events of symfony

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
$category = new Category;
    $category->translate('de')->setName('Foobar');
    $em->persist($category);
    $category->mergeNewTranslations();
    $em->flush();
```